# Import XML into MySQL 5.1

Tags: php, sql, xml

Please excuse my lack of knowledge... I know there is a lot of documentation on the internet related to this but I still don't understand.

My situation is this:

I have an XML file that I need import and eventually replace daily with.

```
    <item>
        <model>AA311-Pink</model>
        <title>1122</title>
        <price>19.43</price>
        <category>cat</category>
        <loc>/AA311.html</loc>
        <image>/aa311.jpg</image>
        <description>Item Info</description>
        <weight>0.45</weight>
        <option_type>Color-Color</option_type>
        <option_value>Pink-Pink</option_value>
        <suggested_retail>51.50</suggested_retail>
        <special_handling/>
        <manufacturer>Tantus</manufacturer>
        <manufacturer_code>VB5074 and VB5067</manufacturer_code>
        <packaging>Retail Packaging</packaging>
        <in_stock>Yes</in_stock>
        <lastupdated>2008-11-05 16:35:56</lastupdated>
```

I need to change a handful of the column names automatically and import them into multiple tables in my database.

For instance,

```
    <item>
        <products_model>AA315</products_model>
        <products_name>name</products_name>
        <price>19.43</price>
        <category>cat</category>
        <loc>/AA315.html</loc>
        <products_image>aa315.jpg</products_image>
        <products_description>info</products_description>
        <products_weight>0.44</products_weight>
        <option_type/>
        <option_value/>
        <products_price>51.50</products_price>
        <special_handling/>
        <manufactures_name>Tantus</manufactures_name>
        <manufacturer_code>VA5104</manufacturer_code>
        <packaging>Retail Packaging</packaging>
        <products_status>Yes</products_status>
        <products_last_modified>2008-11-05 16:35:27</products_last_modified>
```

And then import into MySQL DB

Columns:
products_weight, products_model, products_image, products_price, products_last_modified

import into table 'products'

Columns:
products_description, products_name

import into table 'product_description

Also what about the product_id that is automatically created? I can send SQL output of table structure.

I really apprecaite the help... I am willing to pay some if they are willing to create a fully automated procedure to import this file into my database; I am using Zen Cart to host my shopping cart.

Answer (score 1):

You should a read on this - load a XML into MySQL
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

This allow you to do something like this:

```
mysql> LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'items.xml'
    ->   INTO TABLE item
    ->   ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<item>';
```

Comment: The question was referring to MySQL Version 5.1, where `LOAD XML` is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

No paying required, [Using XML in MySQL 5.1 and 6.0](http://web.archive.org/web/20100105150533/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing) will answer most of your questions. Also, go back to the top and read the entire page, you can do a lot with XML and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thanks gx, http://web.archive.org/web/20100105150533/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing did it for me. I used the stored procedure mentioned there, it however has a small bug if you want to import into another table than 't1'. Just replace line

```
SET @ins_text = CONCAT('INSERT INTO t1 (', ins_list, ') VALUES (', val_list, ')');
```

with

```
SET @ins_text = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', database_name, '.', table_name, ' (', ins_list, ') VALUES (', val_list, ')');
```

Execute the procedure via

```
call xmldump_load('<filename>', '<schema>', '<tablename>');
```

Before calling this procedure make sure the file to import is accessible, for instance in the data folder of mysql (/var/lib/mysql/) and execute it with a user with FILE grant.