# Batch XML import - best/fastest way?

Tags: php, xml

I am doing batch import of products from XML to DB. I need to update these products once a day.

Now, I am doing these steps:

1. Read 1 product from XML
2. Search by product code in DB
3. If product exists, update data, otherwise, insert it
4. Go to step 1 :)

But this method tooks 2 hours for XML with 40 000 products.

I have no idea, how to improve it. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: *(reference)* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import XML into MySQL 5.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294771/import-xml-into-mysql-5-1)

Comment: if you are not using MySql please state which RDBMS you are using.

Comment: what is the source of XML? can you make some modification of it?

Comment: I am using MySQL
Source of XML is XML downloaded from another site. I can do some modification. Where are you heading with it?

Comment: Gordon: That LOAD XML in MySQL looks great, I didn't know it before.

Comment: @Blaskovic I assumed so, that's why I linked you to it ;)

Comment: But can run your code as cron or command line

Answer (score 0):

Good way to start would be to find where the delay is (most likely the database lookups if you are reading the file from a disk).

Consider a worker / producer pattern for the operation, have one thread read from the input file and several threads pull units of work from a queue.  Your unit of work in this case is the product from the XML file.  The worker would tend to the database inserts.

The database could get a speedup from an index on the product code column, if you do not already have it.  Additionally, consider doing a batch insert of any items into the DB, instead of single record inserts.

Comment: The delay is in SQL queries. 80k queris select & update/insert is too much. Reading XML is quite good, whole XML in few seconds.
It could be good with threads maybe.

Comment: Absolutely consider threading it and possibly an index on that query column then.  Batch inserts will also really speed things up, depending on what kind of code you use to do it.  Batching operations like that lets a commit take place en masse (say commit every 1000 inserts) instead of commit after each insert.

Answer (score 0):

XML isn't the problem, its the # of queries.  *If possible* do the following:

1. Limit connections and look-ups to the database.  If you're using
   SQL Server, pass the entire XML to a stored procedure, and process
   the XML in the procedure.
2. Don't update, instead do all inserts.  Clean-up old data after the
   import.  Use a transaction for integrity during the import process.
3. Don't compare in the database.  Retrieve all data from the DB first,
   compare with your XML (use XPath), and only update what's needed.
4. Use the database upload mechanism from a text file (same as #2 really), then clean-up the old data as needed.